# Sound Effect Class in background agent

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I want to be able to play an audio file (a sound basically) from the background agent. I am using the following two approaches :

1)

```
    SoundEffectInstance ClockTickInstance;
        StreamResourceInfo ClockTickStream;
        SoundEffect ClockTickSound;
        try {
        ClockTickStream = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(
          @"AudioFiles/NewHighScore.wav", UriKind.Relative));
                ClockTickSound = SoundEffect.FromStream(ClockTickStream.Stream);
                ClockTickInstance = ClockTickSound.CreateInstance();
                ClockTickInstance.IsLooped = true;
                ClockTickInstance.Volume = 1.0f;
                ClockTickInstance.Pitch = 1.0f;
                ClockTickInstance.Play();
                ClockTickInstance.Stop();
}
```

OR

2)

```
var localFolder = Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
Stream fileStream = await localFolder.OpenStreamForReadAsync("NewHighScore.wav");

byte[] buffer = new byte[fileStream.Length];
fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(fileStream.Length));
fileStream.Close();
SoundEffect soundefct = new SoundEffect(buffer, 16000, AudioChannels.Mono);
FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
soundefct.Play();
```

When i run the code from the xaml.cs file (i.e. from the foreground app) evrything works fine and the sound is played.

But from the background agent, the code runs but no sound is heard.

What could be the problem?

the following article shows the list of APIs that can be used while the app is running in the background -
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662941(v=vs.105).aspx